readr has no reasons to say there are less columns than expected
I'm trying to read the following CSV file from partyfacts with readr.
The import results in problems, but in reality there are no problems.
download.file("https://partyfacts.herokuapp.com/download/external-parties-csv/", "partyfacts-external-parties.csv")
df <- readr::read_csv("partyfacts-external-parties.csv", show_col_types = FALSE)


Warning: One or more parsing issues, call problems() on your data frame for details,
e.g.:
dat <- vroom(...)
problems(dat)

Let's see what we have:
nrow(problems(df))


86

problems(df)[1,]


# A tibble: 1 × 5
row   col expected   actual     file
<int> <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
35519    15 17 columns 15 columns /home/raffaele/Downloads/external-parties.csv

But in reality there are no problems.
Row 35519 is:

BIH,elecglob,292,SNSD,Alliance of Independent Social Democrats,Alliance of Independent Social Democrats,1998,2014,19.1,2006,,,2019-02-08 19:26:26.193233+00:00,2021-03-12 10:15:38.362019+00:00,30450,292,2019-02-08 19:26:26.296626+00:00

Which correctly contains 17 columns, not 15.
The other 84 problems are of the same nature (read less columns than expected) and a similar reasoning applies (the number of columns in the source file is correct).
EDIT: The text I reported for the line is from getting it from a text editor. Apparently the line numbers are not the same I get from R.

A problem in row X of the file means a problem in row X-1 of the dataframe, as you should include the header row in the count. When I do this, all of the reported problems have NA values in the last two columns, which suggests the data is indeed missing.

@user2554330 Apparently the line numbers imported in R doesn't match the line numbers I get from opening the file with a text editor. But again I don't understand what's wrong with the CSV file. Both R base read.csv and python pandas can read it correctly. The number of commas is correct, and field values with commas inside are double quoted.

The file is huge, so it's hard to examine.  A way to diagnose problems like this is to make the file smaller by deleting lines that are fine.  I did that, and obtained this file, keeping only the first two lines, the first line that showed an error, and one line after that (which also shows an error):
country,dataset_key,dataset_party_id,name_short,name,name_english,year_first,year_last,share,share_year,description,comment,created,modified,external_id,partyfacts_id,linked
ALB,manifesto,75721,DBSH,E Djatha e Bashkuar e Shqipërisë,United Albanian Right,1996,1997,5.0,1996,,,2013-01-01 18:18:05.413000+00:00,2023-06-05 10:39:57.075788+00:00,1914,674,2013-01-01 18:33:17.889000+00:00
BEN,gps,60,ABT,,Alliance pour un Benin triomphant,2011,2019,2.9,2015,,,2020-07-16 17:39:48.143406+00:00,2021-03-12 10:16:03.729055+00:00,47733
BEN,gps,64,AE,,Eclaireur,2011,2019,3.7,2015,,,2020-07-16 17:39:57.563352+00:00,2021-03-12 10:16:03.731436+00:00,48035

The third and fourth lines shown above were somewhere around line 35440 in the original file, and as you can see, they don't follow the same format as the previous line:  the final two fields are missing.
read.csv() doesn't complain about this file, because it is documented to fill in missing fields with blanks unless you call it with fill = FALSE.  When I do that I get an error.

Thank you. Why the line number reported by readr is incorrect?

It's correct on the file I have.
